# How to insert multi-colored text within Vegas Pro 13?

Tags: video, video-editing, sony-vegas

I am trying to make a simple text frame with two different colored text segments, but I cannot seem to be able to do it.

I insert the first color fine, but if I change the color for the next section for example then the first portion of text changes too.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 (not quite flexible):** 
in Timeline, add a track above the current, and there insert another colored text, above the first track.

**Method 2 (better):** 
Use "ProType Filter", from "Media Generator" tab.

(source: [Adding Multi-color text in Magix](https://www.protectpages.com/blog/add-multi-color-text-sony-magix-vegas/) )